# Tailwind: how to set autofill of grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have 2 divs under 1 div.

first div should be w-64.

second div's width want to be the rest except for 64.

How to make it?

and if I use `grid` then how to make that?

```html
<div className="w-screen h-screen">
   <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-64 h-screen" >
   </div>
   <div className="flex bg-blue-100 justify-center items-center">
      {children}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to the second div two **Tailwind** properties:

1. `w-[calc(100vw-16rem)]`, where `100vw` is a fullscreen and `w-64 = width: 16rem; /* 256px */`),  then we calculate the width of the div.
2. After that we offset the second div with `ml-auto`.

```html
<div className="w-screen h-screen">
  <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-64 h-screen"></div>
  <div className="grid w-[calc(100vw-16rem)] ml-auto bg-blue-100 justify-center items-center">
    {children}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

##### Grid solution

For the grid, we need to add a `grid` property to the parent element and set two columns `grid-cols-[16rem_calc(100vw-16rem)]`. The first column is static, and the second is responsive. We also need to remove all properties from the first child element.

```html
<div className="grid grid-cols-[16rem_calc(100vw-16rem)] w-screen h-screen ">
  <div className="flex"></div>
  <div className="flex bg-blue-100 justify-center items-center">
     {children}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]